# Simpler way to retrieve multiple values from array

Tags: javascript, arrays, postman

A simpler way to loop through response.Body array and retrieve values of specific elements Id and DataFields.Value - to be used in console log

RESPONSE BODY - this is what is returned when request sent in Postman

```
[
    {
        "Id": "ae61098c-eb7c-4ee8-aca7-aa080112d656",
        "DataFields": [
            {
                "Header": "LocationDetails.LocationID",
                "Value": "BH127"
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        "Id": "84cd9a9f-d085-4642-b484-aa080112d656",
        "DataFields": [
            {
                "Header": "LocationDetails.LocationID",
                "Value": "BH128"
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        "Id": "6629d92b-1dcf-4fc1-a019-aa080112d656",
        "DataFields": [
            {
                "Header": "LocationDetails.LocationID",
                "Value": "BH129"
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        "Id": "47442b4f-f691-4213-b705-aa080112d656",
        "DataFields": [
            {
                "Header": "LocationDetails.LocationID",
                "Value": "BH130"
            }
        ],
    }
]
```

MY CODE - JavaScript in Tests tab

```
var logReportDataQryResults = JSON.parse(responseBody);
var locationOne = 0;
var locationTwo = 1;
var locationThree = 2;

var boreholeOne = logReportDataQryResults[locationOne].Id;
const objOne = logReportDataQryResults[locationOne].DataFields.find(({ Header }) => Header == 'LocationDetails.LocationID');
const holeOne = objOne ? objOne.Value : 'Not Found';

var boreholeTwo = logReportDataQryResults[locationTwo].Id;
const objTwo = logReportDataQryResults[locationTwo].DataFields.find(({ Header }) => Header == 'LocationDetails.LocationID');
const holeTwo = objTwo ? objTwo.Value : 'Not Found';

var boreholeThree = logReportDataQryResults[locationThree].Id;
const objThree = logReportDataQryResults[locationThree].DataFields.find(({ Header }) => Header == 'LocationDetails.LocationID');
const holeThree = objThree ? objThree.Value : 'Not Found';
```

I want to make code more efficient and readable

Comment: Are you trying to get the `Value` to the item with `Header` "LocationDetails.LocationID" and do that for the first three objects in this array?

Comment: @VLAZ, yes I am

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are always using the same pattern (changing parts written in ALL_UPPERCASE):

```
var boreholeOne = logReportDataQryResults[ LOCATION ].Id;
const objOne = logReportDataQryResults[ LOCATION ].DataFields.find(({ Header }) => Header == 'LocationDetails.LocationID');
const holeOne = objOne ? objOne.Value : 'Not Found';
```

You can encapsulate it in a function and pass the changing parts into it:

```
const getBoreholeValue = (locationId, data) => {
  const id = data[locationId].Id;
  const obj = data[locationId].DataFields.find(({ Header }) => Header == 'LocationDetails.LocationID');
  return obj ? obj.Value : 'Not Found';
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
const res1 = getBoreholeValue(0, logReportDataQryResults);
const res2 = getBoreholeValue(1, logReportDataQryResults);
const res3 = getBoreholeValue(2, logReportDataQryResults);
```

Example:

```js
const respBody = [
    {
        "Id": "ae61098c-eb7c-4ee8-aca7-aa080112d656",
        "DataFields": [
            {
                "Header": "LocationDetails.LocationID",
                "Value": "BH127"
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        "Id": "84cd9a9f-d085-4642-b484-aa080112d656",
        "DataFields": [
            {
                "Header": "LocationDetails.LocationID",
                "Value": "BH128"
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        "Id": "6629d92b-1dcf-4fc1-a019-aa080112d656",
        "DataFields": [
            {
                "Header": "LocationDetails.LocationID",
                "Value": "BH129"
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        "Id": "47442b4f-f691-4213-b705-aa080112d656",
        "DataFields": [
            {
                "Header": "LocationDetails.LocationID",
                "Value": "BH130"
            }
        ],
    }
]

const getBoreholeValue = (locationId, data) => {
  const id = data[locationId].Id;
  const obj = data[locationId].DataFields.find(({ Header }) => Header == 'LocationDetails.LocationID');
  return obj ? obj.Value : 'Not Found';
}

console.log(getBoreholeValue(0, respBody));
console.log(getBoreholeValue(1, respBody));
console.log(getBoreholeValue(2, respBody));
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use a single object instead of lots of separate variables - use `.map` to iterate over the locations and construct a new array with the info you need:

```js
const logReportDataQryResults = [
    {
        "Id": "ae61098c-eb7c-4ee8-aca7-aa080112d656",
        "DataFields": [
            {
                "Header": "LocationDetails.LocationID",
                "Value": "BH127"
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        "Id": "84cd9a9f-d085-4642-b484-aa080112d656",
        "DataFields": [
            {
                "Header": "LocationDetails.LocationID",
                "Value": "BH128"
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        "Id": "6629d92b-1dcf-4fc1-a019-aa080112d656",
        "DataFields": [
            {
                "Header": "LocationDetails.LocationID",
                "Value": "BH129"
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        "Id": "47442b4f-f691-4213-b705-aa080112d656",
        "DataFields": [
            {
                "Header": "LocationDetails.LocationID",
                "Value": "BH130"
            }
        ],
    }
]

const locations = [0, 1, 2];
const boreholes = locations.map((location) => {
  const { Id, DataFields } = logReportDataQryResults[location];
  const obj = DataFields.find(({ Header }) => Header == 'LocationDetails.LocationID');
  const holeValue = obj ? obj.Value : 'Not Found';
  return { Id, obj, holeValue };
});
console.log(boreholes);
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't notice your answer was first. And it is better than mine, therefor => upvote! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
    var logReportDataQryResults = 
        [
        {
            "Id": "ae61098c-eb7c-4ee8-aca7-aa080112d656",
            "DataFields": [
                {
                    "Header": "LocationDetails.LocationID",
                    "Value": "BH127"
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            "Id": "84cd9a9f-d085-4642-b484-aa080112d656",
            "DataFields": [
                {
                    "Header": "LocationDetails.LocationID",
                    "Value": "BH128"
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            "Id": "6629d92b-1dcf-4fc1-a019-aa080112d656",
            "DataFields": [
                {
                    "Header": "LocationDetails.LocationID",
                    "Value": "BH129"
                }
            ],
        },
        {
            "Id": "47442b4f-f691-4213-b705-aa080112d656",
            "DataFields": [
                {
                    "Header": "LocationDetails.LocationID",
                    "Value": "BH130"
                }
            ],
        }
        ]



    const boreholes=[];

    for (key in logReportDataQryResults) {

        const { Id, DataFields } = logReportDataQryResults[key];
        const obj = DataFields.find(({ Header }) => Header == 'LocationDetails.LocationID');
        const holeValue = obj ? obj.Value : 'Not Found';
        boreholes.push({ "Id": Id,"holeValue": holeValue });
    }
    console.log(boreholes)
```